Lexicographic convention for indicating the pitch accent if the part of speech has no 平板/heiban–vs–尾高/odaka (word-final H(-H) vs H(-L)) contrast
If a word's pitch accent contour ends in a high pitch, how do lexicographic resources usually indicate it if the word's part of speech doesn't allow for a contrast between word-final H(-H) (unaccented, 平板 heiban) and H(-L) (nucleus on last syllable, 尾高 odaka)?
For a hypothetical word [あかさ]{LHH}, which of the following two pitch accent contours would a dictionary, pitch accent manual, or learning resource normally indicate?

あかさ￣ (notation for あかさ without downstep)
あかさ＼ (notation for あかさꜜ)

Another way of putting this is: If there is no syntactic test available for a particular word (or word class, such as an entire part of speech) that could distinguish 平板 heiban and 尾高 odaka, what is the lexicographic convention for such cases?

always 平板 heiban
always 尾高 odaka
publisher-dependent

The reason for asking is to ease the load on memorization: If one knows that a particular word class doesn't make a distinction, one needs to expend fewer mental resources on trying to memorize the distinction.

Dictionaries would indicate the accent of that word is either 0 or 3. That's if I understood your question correctly.

@aguijonazo The question is: If there is no meaningful contrast between a 0-accent and an n-accent for some word (because it can't be followed by a particle which interacts with the preceding morpheme's pitch accent), do resources generally indicate the accent as 0 or as n? Or does every dictionary follow its own conventions, without there being standard editorial practice?

My dictionary has 0 for きっと.

@aguijonazo Which lexicographic resource did you consult? My 新明解 pitch accent manual has the following two entries for キット: (i)
[キット]{LHH} (0)　(～来る, ～雨だ); (ii) [キット]{HLL} (1), [キット]{LHH} (0)　(～にらむ, ～なる). I would like to emphasize that there, in the 0 cases, there is no descending hook at the end of the horizontal pitch line (the pitch accent notation of Japanese Language Stack Exchange doesn't show this contrast unless special tricks are employed).

(That is: The 新明解 pitch accent manual in principle makes a distinction between the 'word-final accent' and 'unaccented' types, but I added the numbers in parentheses by myself, since I don't trust that if I employ any of the linked-to special workarounds to get a final descending red line, this will be rendered in a stable way on this site for all eternity.)

I was talking about the first sense, whose pitch is not affected by what follows, and my dictionary is スーパー大辞林.

Can you give an example of an odaka word (not a hypothetical word, but a real word) for which the downstep never occurs?  I'm not sure why something would be labeled odaka if there is never an occasion when the downstep would happen.

@A.Ellett I interpret your comment as a rhetorical question, stating that it would be strange to label such words as 尾高 odaka. This is a reasonable view to have – but the empirical question of how dictionaries have traditionally handled this remains to be answered.

@LoverofStructure, I think any dictionary would record a term without downstep as heiban.  The zero used in dictionaries like Daijirin is to indicate "no downstep", i.e. heiban.  Simply by definition, any word for which downstep never occurs would be heiban.

@EiríkrÚtlendi Your statement relies on the assumption that "no downstep" is the default, which follows from a semantic interpretation of the 平板 terminology. This is reasonable. But to a beginner like me, 平板 heiban and 尾高 odaka are simply two different equal possibilities. I didn't even know these terms when first asking the question. Either way, there is no point speculating if it's so easy for some people with access to multiple resources to answer this empirical question. // eg in a hypothetical world where 尾高 odaka is far more common, assuming it as the default would make sense.

Apologies for assuming you knew more than you did; the phrasing you've used so far made it sound like you were already at least somewhat familiar with terminology and conventions.  To provide a quick summary: 平板【へいばん】 means roughly "flat", no downstep, and is annotated in many dictionaries with a zero [0]. If a word has a downstep, dictionaries indicate the number of the mora after which the downstep occurs: [1], [2]. etc. If the downstep happens at the end of the word (such that a following particle is pronounced at a notably lower voice pitch), that word is called 尾高【おだか】 or "tail high".

If the downstep occurs on the first mora of a word, that word is called 頭高【あたまだか】 or "head high".  If the downstep occurs in the middle, that word is called 中高【なかだか】 or "middle high". Depending on usage, you may see the word 型【がた】 ("type, shape, kind") appended to the accent names. Most Chinese-derived on'yomi two-kanji terms are either heiban or atamadaka. Many verbs are nakadaka; I think most (all?) verbs ending in -eru and -aru have the downstep right after the "e" or "a". Oh, and pinging just in case: @LoverofStructure
